# Ethical Hacking

Tags: united-states, hacking, digital-forensics

How is Ethical Hacking (Certified Ethical Hackers) defined by U.S. law?

Is there any law which protects an Ethical Hacker for helping to find out bugs and security loopholes in online/digital services being used by a corporation/government agency?

What is the stand of other countries on this matter?

Comment: I have always wondered about this too..

Comment: Try to limit the scope to the United States. So I'd remove the line "What is the stand of other countries on this matter?".

Comment: I live in India, and major software corporations are from US, so I'd like to know whatever I could about these two countries for sure. Info about other countries would be welcome as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to U.S. Law to be employed by the government. You would need to be certified to DoDD8570 specs. Here is a [baseline](https://www.sans.org/media/dod8570/dod8570.pdf) to understand what certifications are required depending on the role you are looking to be gainfully employed. These mostly require being [GIAC](http://www.giac.org) certified among some of the other certifications.

In regards to becoming a "Certified Ethical Hacker", you would need to pass the CEH test by the [ECCouncil](http://www.eccouncil.org/Certification/certified-ethical-hacker).

As for laws protecting "Ethical Hackers", there really isn't any. The law which applies is mostly for prosecuting criminal acts. Not really for the protection of the security consultant. This law is called [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) in the U.S. and in the U.K. the [Computer Misuse Act 1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Misuse_Act_1990).

Comment: Please also state in what conditions would "Certified Ethical Hacker" be revoked?

Comment: During the mandatory class for CEH they cover how to protect yourself when engaging in offensive security.  The training advised to have a carefully worded waiver signed by the client before any action is taken.

Comment: CEH is not the only cert, and it is a rather terrible one at that. There are better examples.